# BackHandler does not go back more than 1 screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have this code on each of my screens. Pressing the android back button goes back 1 screen. Pressing android back button again does not do anything. Expected result would be to keep going back as long as there are more screens in the stack. What's missing?

```
componentWillMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
        this.props.navigation.goBack();
        return true;
    });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress')
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After some trial and error, this code works as expected. I believe my initial code was not actually removing the event listener.

```
componentWillMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.backPressed);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.backPressed);
}

backPressed = () => {
    this.props.navigation.goBack();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I am getting error message "Cant read property navigation of undefined". What can be the issue?

Comment: If you are using react-navigation try to set it up like they have in the docs.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/guides/redux#Handling-the-Hardware-Back-Button-in-Android

Comment: What is the utility of the `return true`? I had the same problem as you and adding it solved it for me...

Comment: @AlexandreRivest according to a comment in the definition of the `BackHandler`: `Detect hardware back button presses, and programmatically invoke the default back button functionality to exit the app if there are no listeners or if none of the listeners return true.`

Comment: @JustinLok I implemented the three functions in the class of the screen where I want to go back through the button ... clicking the button, however, nothing happens (it does not come out even more from the app as it did before, which is fine) I put an alert to `this. props.navigation` and contains an empty 'Actions' array and the 'State' array with Key and RouteName with the same name of the screen ... the official documentation is very poor, I do not understand if something is needed in the app. js to manage everything or anywhere else ... I hope you can help me :-)

Comment: @AlexandreRivest same, my app would crash even when `componentWillUnmount` fires till I returned true instead of false